# create index on couchbase for ARRAY_REMOVE

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I want to execute this query :

```
UPDATE `bucket` SET etats= ARRAY_REMOVE( etats, etats[2])
```

my question is how to create an index to execute this query, i don't want to use

primary index couchbase.

the goal of the query is to remove an element from array 'etats'.

example of the document :

```
{
  "lastUpdateTime": "2019-03-31T22:02:00.164",
  "origin": "origin1",
  "etats": [
    {
      "dateTime": "2019-03-28T17:13:49.766",
      "etat": "etat1",
      "code": "code1"
    },
    {
      "dateTime": "2019-03-29T15:26:48.577",
      "etat": "etat2",
      "code": "code2"
    },
    {
      "dateTime": "2019-03-31T22:01:59.843",
      "etat": "etat3",
      "code": "code3"
    }
  ],
  "etatType": "type1"
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example or two of the documents?

Comment: Also, it looks like this query is designed to affect *every* document in the bucket, so I'm not sure an index would help very much.

Comment: @MatthewGroves  please find an example of the document, i edit the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have WHERE clause to choose index, otherwise only option is primary index.
In general you check elements if present then only do update the field.
The following query removes object from array that have code value "code2"

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default (DISTINCT ARRAY v.code FOR v IN etats END) WHERE etatType = "type1";

UPDATE default AS d  
SET d.etats = ARRAY v FOR v IN d.etats WHEN v.code != "code2" END
WHERE d.etatType = "type1" AND ANY v IN d.etats SATISFIES v.code = "code2" END;
```

If you really want index for your query only.

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON  `bucket` (etatType);

UPDATE `bucket` SET etats= ARRAY_REMOVE( etats, etats[2])
WHERE etatType = "type1";
```